# Which server is a batch file executed from?

Tags: batch-file, scheduled-tasks, remote-server

Is there a way to have a batch file determine the IP/Name of the server from which it is being triggered (i.e. when it's executed on a separate server to the one triggering the execution)?

My initial thought is to add the line `netstat -a >> WhoDunnit.txt` so that I can see all connections moments after the script's called, then trawl through that hoping the connection was still open; but asking here in case there's a more sophisticated solution?

**Background**

- We recently found a deployment script was being run at 2am each week, with no one having any knowledge of why.
- The script's commands mean it will only affect the server on which it's running, so it must be executing locally.
- The script's host server has nothing defined in its scheduled tasks / we can't see anything on this machine that would trigger this script.
- So the script must be being called from some other server on which the schedule's defined, but in such a way that it executes on the host server rather than on the triggering server.
- If I can find which server's calling the script I can find the schedule and disable it.

Comment: You can not change the script as you will not be sure if the script being executed is the local one or it is deployed on each execution. Better check the windows event logs.

Comment: Can you interrogate the task scheduler on every server and search for the script name?  If the name is not unique then if the task is not critical, rename the script and after you get the task scheduler list from every server, search for the errors.

Comment: Thanks @MCND.  I'm pretty confident it's the script on the host rather than a copy since we're seeing log files in the same directory.  Once I amend that script to report the calling user we'd be able to tell for sure since only the amended script would produce the new output.

Comment: Good call @foxidrive; though sadly we don't have anything that sophisticated, so writing something to query all our server's event logs / task schedulers would be a pretty epic task.

Comment: `SCHTASKS /Query /?` will show you the syntax to query the tasks on any machine and a simple loop with the list of servers can get you the lists in a file.

Comment: If the logs you comment are generated by the batch file, the owner of the logs should be the account used to start the batch.

Answer (score 0):

Batch file with below in it.

```
echo %~dpnx0
```

When started by

```
C:\Users\User>"\\127.0.0.1\C$\users\user\cmdline.bat"
```

returns

```
C:\Users\User>echo \\127.0.0.1\C$\Users\User\cmdline.bat
\\127.0.0.1\C$\Users\User\cmdline.bat
```

Now I would turn process auditing on and wait for it to start.